# Solve irrational inequality $\sqrt{x^2-8x+15} + \sqrt{x^2+2x-15} > \sqrt{4x^2-8x+18}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Here's what I tried

$$\sqrt{x^2-8x+15} + \sqrt{x^2+2x-15} > \sqrt{4x^2-8x+18}$$
$$\sqrt{(x-3)(x-5)} + \sqrt{(x-3)(x+5)} > \sqrt{4x^2-8x+18}$$

Now,

$$(x-3)(x-5) > 0 \Leftrightarrow x \in (- \infty, 3) \cup (5, \infty)$$

$$(x-3)(x+5) > 0 \Leftrightarrow x \in (-\infty, -5) \cup (3, \infty)$$

$$4x^2-8x+18 > 0, \forall x \in R$$

So, for $x \in (- \infty, -5) \cup (5, \infty)$, we can take squares of both sides and we win this:

$$|x-3| \sqrt{(x-5)(x+5)} > x^2 - x + 9$$

Are my steps correct? And what should I do now? Should I solve for $x < -5,$ and for $x>5$?

Thanks.

Comment: May be, what you could look at is the behaviour of $$f(x)=\sqrt{x^2-8x+15} + \sqrt{x^2+2x-15} - \sqrt{4x^2-8x+18}$$ when $x\to\pm \infty$. If you want we elaborate, just post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct so far. for $|x|\geq 5$ both sides of your last equation are positive, so you can square the equation again and solve the remaining equation (it is cubic at most).

Comment: All right, I solved it with a lot of algebraic moves.